# How to set network connection as Internet connection?

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

In Kubuntu 13.04 it looking as that:
[image: Kubuntu network manager]

Wired connection used for Internet access on screenshot (notice globe icon). How to swtich "Internet" status from wired connection to another?

Comment: Are you using 13.10, or is that a typo?

Comment: Yep - 13.04 actually.

Comment: I'm sorry, I fail to understand what the question is. You want to connect only to the wired interface as opposed to both the wired and the wireless interfaces?

Comment: @Alex Check my edits

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Check this image; hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

In kubuntu search for network settings in the start menu. You can edit your connections there.

Comment: Not found such option there, can you point me directly?

Comment: right click on blank area in systems tray -> system tray settings -> click network management